# Too few interactions in a Spock test for a Grails service

Tags: testing, grails, service, spock

I thought I've understood Spock interactions but I have to admin that I'm still missing some pieces of the picture.

Alright, here my problem: I have a method in a Grails service which performs some operations, including a call to a void method of the same service class. Here's the code:

```
class myService {
    void myStuff(def myObj, params) {
        // do my stuff

        anotherMethod(myObj)

        //do my stuff again
    }

    void anotherMethod(myObj) {
        // do other stuff
    }
}
```

I want to be sure that myStuff method calls anotherMethod, to test and document the correct behaviour.

So, here's the test in my Spock Specification class:

```
void 'test myStuff method'() {
    given: 'my object and some params'    
        // doesn't really matter what I'm doing here
        MyObject myObj = new MyObject()
        params = [title: 'my object']

    when: 'we call myStuff()'
        service.myStuff(myObj, params)

    then: 'anotherMethod() is called exactly one times'
        1 * service.anotherMethod(myObj)
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Too few invocations for:

1 * service.anotherMethod(myObj)   (0 invocations)
```

What do you think? What's wrong?

As always, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking for a very special, and generally discouraged, form of mock called *partial mocking* where methods on the *class under test* are mocked. Spock supports this since 0.7, but you'll have to create a `Spy()` rather than a `Mock()`. Also note that you cannot mock private methods. For more information on spies, see the [reference documentation](http://docs.spockframework.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html#spies).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I understand your concerns, basically I'm doing this because the myStuff() method is basically an "alias" for the anotherMethod() invocation with specific parameters, and I want to document this specific behaviour with a test. I'll give a try to the Spy(), taking this time as an opportunity to update the Spock plugin to version 0.7 in my Grails application :)

Comment: Partial mocking and spies worked for me. 

What I did ("code" between double quotes) was to add a Spy in the given section of the test, just like this "def myService = Spy(MyService)" and then use the spy myService instead of the typical 'service' instance.

The rest of the test is pretty straightforward: "when: myService.myStuff(myObj, params) then: 1 * myService.anotherMethod(_)".